# Is something like "that's nice" or "that's dope" in response to someone telling you they just got a new job or new car considered a subjective claim?

Tags: objectivity, subjectivity, critical-thinking

I've been pondering this as well as when someone says they lost their job or got their car stolen and you say things like "that sucks" or "that's unfortunate" and I'm honestly not sure if they're subjective or objective claims. I want to say objective since aren't all those things the case independent of opinion? Hope this doesn't sound too silly but I'm pretty new to philosophy so if anyone could clarify I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: They are not claims at all, this is called being polite. Not every utterance is intended to make a claim, see [perlocutionary acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlocutionary_act), "*intended perlocutionary effect might be to impress the interlocutor, or to show a friendly attitude*".